# Sitecore 9.3 JSS - controller for path '/api/jss/formbuilder' was not found

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms

I'm trying to apply my Sitecore Form on my JSS application through the Forms API. The form was rendered properly, but when I tried to submit I got this error:

[image: controller for path '/api/jss/formbuilder' was not found]

What could be the cause of this? My Sitecore version is 9.3 and my `npm` packages for `sitecore-jss-react` and `sitecore-jss-react-forms` is `^13.2.2` which is the appropriate version for my Sitecore instance.

Comment: It would be good to see your full Stack Trace and more information from the Sitecore log about this error to investigate further.

Answer (score 3):

Basic reasons behind your problem could be either wrong naming convention of your controller or routing issues.

If you added a "Controller" word to your controller file name then this could be why, so simply rename your file and remove the "Controller" word from it.

Routing is important to match URI to an expected action, so ensure that you use the `Routing` attribute to define routes in C#. For any custom routes, make sure that they don't conflict with the default Sitecore routes and create your custom processor with the relevant config settings to add it to the "initialize" pipeline.